# Can I use DVI to RCA Cable to connect my PC to my TV

Tags: graphics-card, tv, dvi, adapter, composite-video

I want to clear my doubt as to whether I can connect my PC to my TV.  My graphics card supports DVI-I and VGA.  I want to connect it to my 29" Sony FD Trinitron Wega KVEF29M80 using a DVI-to-RCA cable. To which port do I connect for the TV?

Comment: "RCA" video connections are called "composite" or "component" depending on whether there's one video plug (usually yellow) or three.  (not counting the red & white audio RCA plugs.)  which one are you trying to use?

Comment: Red, blue and green.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I found for "DVI to RCA cable",  it looks like you would be getting **component** video not **composite**.  Component video connections look like this:

[image: Component Video]

There are 3 plugs.  Composite video is a single yellow cable typically.  Your TV would need to have the component plugs on it in order to do what you are wanting.

If you need composite I would look into a VGA to composite or VGA to S-Video cable, they are readily available and either one should work for your setup.

Comment: Thanks 'heavyd', I Do have Component Video in on my Tv as well as well as an s-video Which one would be better. And will a VGA to RCA cable work or should i go for VGA to Convertor?????

Comment: Since you have component on your TV I would either go  DVI->component or VGA->component.  You may get a slightly better picture with DVI.

Comment: Surely DVI is the answer tnx

Comment: Note that this will only work if your DVI output includes analog signals - not all of them do; some of them are digital only. You may need to fallback to a VGA strategy.